# How to take random rows from spark dataframe using scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What is the canonical way to get random rows from spark dataframe?

For example

Getting random N rows from dataframe

or

Getting random 1% of rows from dataframe

Comment: have you tried [sample]( https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#sample(withReplacement:Boolean,fraction:Double):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T])?